# Passing parameters though wrappers in R

Tags: r

I have a question about passing parameters for functions down through a series of wrappers and the correct way to these sorts of things. Each of these functions aside from the wrapper function are supposed to also work outside of the wrapper if that makes any difference. I apologize for the stupidity or errors within the example, I was struggling to think of something that would explain the problem.

```
# data sets
data("mtcars")
data("starwars")

# Data set list
d.list <- list(mtcars, starwars)
names(d.list) <- c("mtcars", "starwars")


foo_1 <- function(event,data.in){
  data.in[grep(event, names(data.in))]
}

foo_2 <- function(event, data.in, extra, ...){
  a.df <- foo_1(...)
  a.df %>%
    mutate(across(is.numeric, ~ . + extra))
}

foo_wrapper <- function(event, data.in, extra, ...){
  b.df <- foo_2(...)
  c.df <- foo_2(..., extra = 15)
  
  return(list(b.df, c.df))}

foo.this <- foo_wrapper(event = "starwars",
                        data.in = d.list,
                        extra = 12)

# Error in foo_1(...) : argument "data.in" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: You defined `foo_1` with different arguments and is passing `...`

Comment: I see that's what I'm doing, my question is what should I be doing? Within `foo_2` I should be calling `foo_1(event = event, data.in = data.in)`?

Comment: Passing `...` input will be different than the expected in foo_1

Comment: @akrun what does that mean? How should I do it? What is the correct way to pass parameters through multiple layers of functions when they have the same parameter names?